# Is there any built in library for linear kernel in scikit learn like RBF, SE?

Tags: scikit-learn, kernel, gaussian

I want to multiply linear kernel with RBF for a dataset but finding no way to implement linear kernel. How can I implement the linear kernel here.
For example RBF, SE can be used in Scikit learn like :

```
k2 = 2.0**2 * RBF(length_scale=100.0)  

k_exp = ExpSineSquared(length_scale=1.0, periodicity=1.0,
                       periodicity_bounds="fixed")
```

Answer (score 0):

The linear kernel for use in gaussian processes in scikit-learn is provided as the [DotProduct kernel](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.DotProduct.html). According to the [gaussian processes book](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW4.pdf) by Rasmussen and Williams (Chapter 4.2.2) setting sigma_0=0 gives the homogeneous linear kernel whereas otherwise is the inhomogeneous linear kernel. There's an example of using the DotProduct kernel in scikit [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/gaussian_process/plot_gpc_xor.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-gaussian-process-plot-gpc-xor-py). In the case of gaussian processes you don't have to give the vector inputs into DotProduct as you will give them when you call the `.fit(X,Y)` function.

In case you want the dot product two vectors to check their similarity then you can you use [linear kernel](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.linear_kernel.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise.linear_kernel) which gives the dot product of the two vectors (with checks for sparse inputs). Finally note that the [linear kernel](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.linear_kernel.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise.linear_kernel) doesn't have any optional noise term whereas [DotProduct kernel](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.DotProduct.html) does.

Comment: I've also found this one (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.linear_kernel.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise.linear_kernel). What are the parameters I should pass here ?

Comment: I've edited my answer, as I didn't make it clear that the dotproduct is for use in gaussian processes. From the code you give above it seems like you are preparing kernels for use in a gaussian process?